# Merge a third party javascript file into webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, webpack

How can I merge a third party javascript file into my webpack bundle without getting checked on modules etc?

Because my third party javascript file is already bundled.

Answer (score 2):

Well, the ideal would be for it to be bundled together, but you can work around this problem.

First, make sure it is `imported` somewhere on your dependency tree (webpack only knows about your file if it is imported).

Now, to be able to use external files, you have to use the [external](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) configuration.

For eg:

```
module.exports = {
  //...
  externals: {
    jquery: 'jQuery'
  }
};
```

States to webpack that this is going to be available as an external resource  when this application is loaded.

Now you can add your already bundled file to your index.html and serve to the user.

Comment: I don't want to add the third party bundle into my index.html file,  I want it bundled with webpack bundle js file

Is that possible?

Comment: It is and it is not. I've seen bizillions of problems on doing that and not most of people were successful. The only way to do that would be importing into you entrypoint. But you will still find bugs

Comment: Thanks for your help!